# Find the GCD of a polynomial using the extended Euclidean algorithm and express it in the form $a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I am working on a problem that I can not seem to finish.

Find the gcd of $f(x)=x^7+1$ and $g(x)=x^6+x^5+x^3+1$, and express it in the form $a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x)$ using the extended euclidean algorithm.

I have performed the extended euclidean algorithm to find the following
$$f(x)=(x-1)g(x)+(x^5-x^4+x^3-x+2)$$
$$g(x)=(x+2)(x^5-x^4+x^3-x+2)+(x^4-x^3+x^2-3)$$
$$x^5-x^4+x^3-x+2=(x)(x^4-x^3+x^2-3)+(2x+2)$$
$$x^4-x^3+x^2-3=(\frac{1}{2}x^3-x^2+\frac{3}{2}x-\frac{3}{2})(2x+2)+0$$
This should give us the GCD as following
$$\gcd(f,g)=\gcd(x^5-x^4+x^3-x+2, 2x+2)=2x+2$$
And the monic GCD then becomes
$$\gcd(f,g)=x+1$$

This is where I get stuck. Now that I have this I am not sure how to algebraically get back to the form $a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x)$

The answer as provided in the solutions is
$$\gcd(f(x),g(x))=x^4+x^3+x^2+1=xf(x)+(x^2+x+1)g(x)$$

I do not understand how to proceed and get to the answer. I have tried going backward but I am not getting anywhere. How do I go from $x+1$ to the correct solution?

Comment: I think the coefficient of $g(x)$ is $x^2+x+1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Just to let you know, MathJax works in titles, and I've made that upgrade for you.

Answer (score 0):

With some guessing, I figured out that the original question asks the $\gcd$ of these two polynomials over $\Bbb F_2$.

This means that $f, g$ are viewed as polynomials in $\Bbb F_2[x]$. Therefore the algorithm stops at the step $x^5-x^4+x^3-x+2=(x)(x^4-x^3+x^2-3)+(2x+2)$, as the remainder is now $0$.

Comment: Yes I know, but I am trying to express it in the form a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x). I have already found the gcd. The answer provided is not my own, but the answer I am trying to get to from my point before.

Comment: If you know, then you should state this in your question. And I am telling you that the reason that your answer does not match that of the solution is because you are doing computations over $\Bbb Q$ instead of over $\Bbb F_2$.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the misunderstanding. I am not sure how to do this in F2[x]. If it still leads to that line then I assume the first part is correct? Do you have any tips on how to go about getting it into the form a(x)f(x)+b(x)g(x)?

Comment: Basically, thoughout your computation, whenever you get an integer (which is not in the exponent) that is not $0$ or $1$, you replace it with $0$ or $1$ according to its parity (even = $0$, odd = $1$). Everything else works the same way as what you have done. E.g. the first step now becomes $f(x)=(x+1)g(x)+(x^5+x^4+x^3+x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the *extended Euclidean algorithm* works in this case (over $\mathbf F_2$). Keep  in mind that, in characteristic $2$, adding or subtracting is the same.

This extended algorithm is based on the remark that *all* remainders are linear combination of the two given polynomials, and the coefficients thereof are computed recursively.
\begin{array}{rccl}
r_n &u_n&v_n & q_n\\\hline
f(x) & 0 & 1 \\
g(x) & 1 & 0 & x+1 \\ \hline 
x^5+x^4+x^3 + x & x+1 & 1 & x \\ 
x^4+x^3 + x^2 + 1 & 1+x(x+1) & x & x \\[-0.5ex]
&=\color{red}{x^2+x+1} & \color{red}x \\ \hline
0 
\end{array}

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting way to find the solutions for "Bezout's equation" $ax+by=mdc(a,b)$ using continued fractions. For instance, for numbers: find $(x,y) \in \mathbb Z^2$ s.t. $11x + 7y = 1$. The continued fraction of $11/7$ is $[1;1,1,3]$. By removing the last digit, $[1;1,1] = 3/2$, we see that $11 \cdot 2 + 7 \cdot (-3) = 1$, therefore $(x,y) = (2,-3)$ satisfy the equation $11x + 7y = 1$. The thing is: the algorithm is exactly the same for polynomials!

Answer (score 0):

$$  \left(   x^{7}  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{6}  +  x^{5}  +  x^{3}  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{7}  + 1 \right)  =  \left(   x^{6}  +  x^{5}  +  x^{3}  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 1 \right) } +  \left(   x^{5}  -  x^{4}  +  x^{3}  -  x  + 2 \right)  $$
$$  \left(   x^{6}  +  x^{5}  +  x^{3}  + 1 \right)  =  \left(   x^{5}  -  x^{4}  +  x^{3}  -  x  + 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  + 2 \right) } +  \left(   x^{4}  -  x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 3 \right)  $$
$$  \left(   x^{5}  -  x^{4}  +  x^{3}  -  x  + 2 \right)  =  \left(   x^{4}  -  x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 3 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  \right) } +  \left(  2 x  + 2 \right)  $$
$$  \left(   x^{4}  -  x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 3 \right)  =  \left(  2 x  + 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  + 3 x  - 3 }{ 2 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$
$$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  - 1 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x  - 1 \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  + 2 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  - 1 \right) }{ \left(   x  + 2 \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 1 \right) }{ \left(   x^{2}  + 2 x  + 1 \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  + 3 x  - 3 }{ 2 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  x^{6}  -  x^{5}  +  x^{4}  -  x^{3}  +  x^{2}  -  x  + 1 }{ 2 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  x^{5}  +  x^{2}  -  x  + 1 }{ 2 }  \right) } $$
$$  \left(   x^{6}  -  x^{5}  +  x^{4}  -  x^{3}  +  x^{2}  -  x  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x^{2}  + 2 x  + 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{5}  +  x^{2}  -  x  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$
$$  \left(   x^{7}  + 1 \right)  =  \left(   x^{6}  -  x^{5}  +  x^{4}  -  x^{3}  +  x^{2}  -  x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  + 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$  \left(   x^{6}  +  x^{5}  +  x^{3}  + 1 \right)  =  \left(   x^{5}  +  x^{2}  -  x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  + 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(   x  + 1 \right) }   $$
$$  \left(   x^{7}  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x^{2}  + 2 x  + 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{6}  +  x^{5}  +  x^{3}  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 1 }{ 2 }  \right)  =  \left(   x  + 1 \right)  $$

.......